# Java - Calling JasperReport with ActionListener

Tags: java, report

The im trying to implement a report into a Java Program. I have a Form that a user will fill in and at the end ill have a "Print Report" button.

What i need that to do is send the array of Strings through to a method that will fill a JasperReport as parameters.

I have the JasperReport JRXML file set up and have the TextFields equals to the parameters. I just want to send in parameters from a Java Program and then print the report.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer following code. Place it into your listener.

```
        File file=new File("demo.jrxml");
        InputStream stream=new FileInputStream(file);
        JasperDesign design=JRXmlLoader.load(stream);
        JasperReport report=JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);

        Map<String, Object> params=new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("param1", "data1"); // note here you can add parameters which would be utilized by the report

        JasperPrint print=JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, params,new JREmptyDataSource());
        //use JasperExportManager to export report to your desired requirement
```

`Note:`You can specify as many parameters you want, and the data source I have used is `JREmptyDataSource`, you can specify according to your requirements.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thats really great. I cant fully test it yet as i haven't figured out the reports fully. I seem to to create a Jasper File. Do i send through an SQL Query as a parameter or all the variables as parameters?

Comment: OK so what i need to know now is how to display it on screen with the option to print. maybe just send it through to the printer and Windows will show a print preview.

Comment: Firstly what parameters to send depends on your report. If you want to directly show values on report send them as parameter. Or you can always place your query in the report itself.

Comment: Second, you can use `JasperViewer` to view the report. Lastly any upvote or acceptance or even both will be appreciated if the assistance helped you.

Comment: Hi Thats really great. I have it all working apart from one little thing. Im having a problem with Boolean. I have a condition "<![CDATA[$P{ShellPress15}.equalsIgnoreCase("true") ? "tick.jpg" : "tick1.jpg"]]>". In the database its stored as a boolean but wether its true or false the condition is never true. Im sure the condition is wrong. How do you correctly condition a Boolean?

Comment: If `$P{ShellPress15}` is a boolean value simply do. `$P{ShellPress15}.booleanValue()==true? "tick.jpg" : "tick1.jpg"`. If it is string you are doing it correctly.

Comment: Thank you. Its a boolean. Works 100%. Thanks very much for the help.